# How to decrement a variable once per 52 iterations of a while loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
h=0
l=0
while read user_input;
do
    [ "$user_input" -eq 1 ] && ((h++))
    [ "$user_input" -eq 2 ] && ((l--))

    echo "         $(($((h+l))/6))"
done
```

I need the divided by six portion to reduce to 5 after 52 user input reads, and 4 after 52 more, etc. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
h=0
l=0
reads=0
divider=6
while read user_input;
do
    ((reads++))
    [ "$user_input" -eq 1 ] && ((h++))
    [ "$user_input" -eq 2 ] && ((l--))
    if [ "$((reads%52))" -eq 0 -a "$divider" -gt 1 ]; then
        ((divider--))
    fi
    echo "         $(($((h+l))/divider))"
done
```